# Android: BroadcastReceiver not getting called from my Service

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am new to Android Development. I have defined a test app with a service, where I declare a BroadcastReceiver for receiving Bluetooth events -

```
public class MyService extends Service
 {
  BluetoothEventsReceiver mBluetoothEventsReceiver = null;

   @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent i, int flags, int startId) {

        // register the receiver to listen for Bluetooth Connected/Dis-connected events
        if (mBluetoothEventsReceiver != null) {
            mBluetoothEventsReceiver = new BluetoothEventsReceiver();

            Log.e(TAG, "Register receiver=" + mBluetoothEventsReceiver);
            IntentFilter intent = new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED");
            intent.addAction("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED");

            getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mBluetoothEventsReceiver, intent);
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(i, flags, startId);
   }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null; 
    }
}
```

My BroadcastReceiver is defined as

```
public class BluetoothEventsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Received Event" + " ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED" );
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Log.e(TAG, "device=" + device);        

        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Received Event" + " ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED" );
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Log.e(TAG, "device=" + device);
        }
    }
}
```

I start the Service from my Activity, and I expect the BroadcastReceiver to print log messages when I connect and disconnect Bluetooth headset, but no logs are printed. So, I guess its not called.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    // Debugging
    public final static String TAG ="MyActivity";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.e(TAG, "Starting service");
        startService(new Intent(".MyService"));

    }
```

Also, when I add the receiver to the Manifest file, then the BluetoothEventsReceiver is invoked. But from my understanding, I do not need to declare the receiver in the Manifest file, if I want the receiver to be active only when the Service is running.

I do have the permissions set in the Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyService" android:process=":remote">
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- These are the interfaces supported by the service, which
        you can bind to. -->
            <action android:name=".MyService" />
        </intent-filter>
        </service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Please help debug what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

change your intent filter from this:

```
IntentFilter intent = new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED");
intent.addAction("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED");
```

to this:

```
 IntentFilter intent = new IntentFilter();
 intent.addAction("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED");
 intent.addAction("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED");
```

It seems that the filter that you created doesn't match to bluetooth intents as they do have extra data attached while your filter works only for empty intents having only an action.

Here is the javadoc for the API:

public IntentFilter (String action) 
Since: API Level 1 
New IntentFilter that matches a single action with no data. If no data characteristics are subsequently specified, then the filter will only match intents that contain no data.

Comment: No, I made this change, but still the broadcastreceiver is not invoked

Answer (score 0):

This `startService(new Intent(".MyService"))` won't work. You need to provide the actual path of the Service class name. Relative path is only used in AndroidManifest file, it should not be used in codes.

Try something like this in your activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
this.startService(intent);
```

where **MyService** refers to the actual fully-qualified name of your service.